# Can Ubuntu touch run VS code?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, visual-studio-code

Is it possible for Ubuntu touch run VS code?
I'm trying to install Ubuntu touch for development purposes. Mainly for VS code since I'm limited with the time I use my computer.

Comment: In theory you can try VScodium from https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/releases and launch it inside [Libertine](https://docs.ubports.com/en/latest/userguide/dailyuse/libertine.html) container.

Answer (score 1):

It can in theory run anything Ubuntu 16.04 can run, but that's not an application designed for a small screen, also for the power consumption needs of a smartphone, also there's no good way to install (UT doesn't have snap support, and lots of deb package dependencies might be missing). You can possibly find better options for UT on the Open Store at: https://open-store.io/?category=Developer%20Tools